# JQuery closest elements, from TextBox in a GridView

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, closest

I've this javascript function:

```
function modifica(txtValoreID, txtRicalcolatoID, lblDeltaID) {
  // Ricalcolo il valore aggiornato
  var Valore = parseFloat($("#" + txtValoreID).val()).toFixed(2);
  var Ricalcolato = parseFloat($("#" + txtRicalcolatoID).val()).toFixed(2);
  $("#" + lblDeltaID).html(parseFloat(Valore - Ricalcolato).toFixed(2).replace('.', ','));
}
```

That refers to textbox and label in a gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValore" Width="90%" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:N}", Eval("Valore"))%>' runat="server"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRicalcolato" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:N}", Eval("Ricalcolato")) %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

(...)

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delta"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDelta" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:N}", Eval("Delta"))%>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And I'm assigning it in the DataBound:

```
txtValore.Attributes.Add("onchange", "modifica('" + txtValore.ClientID + "', '" + txtRicalcolato.ClientID + "','" + lblDelta.ClientID + "')");
txtRicalcolato.Attributes.Add("onchange", "modifica('" + txtDaLiquidare.ClientID + "', '" + txtRicalcolato.ClientID + "','" + lblDelta.ClientID + "')");
```

and it's working perfectly. The problem is that when the gridview have a lot of records, databound is affecting the performance, so my first question is, am I improving this performance moving the assignment from databound server code to aspx page? And if yes, how can I do that? Because I'm trying like this:

```
asp:TextBox ID="txtValore" onchange="test(this.id)" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:N}", Eval("PremioLiquidare"))%>' runat="server"  />
```

and this:

```
function test(txtID) {
    alert('TEST ' + $(this));
    alert('TEST ' + $(this).val());
    alert('TEST ' + $("#" + txtID).val());
    alert('TEST ' + $("#" + txtID).find("[id*='txtRicalcolato']").val());
    alert('TEST ' + $("#" + txtID).closest("[id*='txtRicalcolato']").val());
    alert('TEST ' + $(this).find("[id*='txtRicalcolato']").val());
    alert('TEST ' + $(this).closest("[id*='txtRicalcolato']").val());    
}
```

But the first is printing TEST Object object, the second blank and the third the correct value, but the others are undefined.. What I'm doing wrong?

The rendered HTML is:

```
<table class="mGrid" id="ctl00_MainContent_grid">
    <tbody>
        (...)
        <tr>
            (...)
            <td>
                <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grid$ctl03$txtValore" value="1.693,44" id="ctl00_MainContent_grid_ctl03_txtValore" onchange="test(this.id)" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grid$ctl03$txtRicalcolato" value="169,34" id="ctl00_MainContent_grid_ctl03_txtRicalcolato" onchange="test(this.id)" type="text">
            </td>
            (...)
            <td>
                <span id="ctl00_MainContent_grid_ctl03_lblDelta">-1.524,10</span>
            </td>
            (...)
        </tr>
        (...)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of adding *attribute-based* change handlers, use a single delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor element (e.g. a surrounding `table` or `div`). This has a much lower overhead and keeps all the code in one place.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, if you can provide an example of the actual HTML from the browser, not source code, I can provide a more specific example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to search from the element down with `find`, and the element upwards with `closest` but the *target element* is in another branch of the DOM.

- `find` only searches from the element downwards (its descendants)
- `closest` searches the *ancestors* only (not literally the closest match).

You need to search *up* with `closest`, *then* `find` *down*:

e.g. the 3rd and 4th ones should be:

```
    alert('TEST ' + $("#" + txtID).closest('someCommonParentElementSelector').find("[id*='txtRicalcolato']").val());
```

**Suggestion: Use a single *Delegated Event Handler***

Instead of adding *attribute-based* change handlers, use a single delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor element (e.g. a surrounding `table` or `div`). This has a much lower overhead and keeps all the code in one place.

Based on your new HTML example, a delegated event handler would go something like this:

```
// Shortcut DOM ready handler
$(function(){
    // Listen for change events bubbling up to the grid, 
    // then match elements with ID ending in "txtValore"
    $('.mGrid').on('change', 'input[id$="txtValore"]' function(){

          // this is the *txtValore field that changed
          var $input = $(this);

          // Find the matching input by looking up (to closest row) and then down the tree
          // for an element with ID ending in "txtRicalcolato"
          var $otherInput = $input.closest('tr').find('input[id$="txtRicalcolato"]');

          // now do "something" with the two inputs :)
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

- You can then remove any `onChange` attributes from your inputs.
- This makes the setup simpler and puts the event handler code *with* the event handler registration.
- If there are no dynamically added elements, you could just use a jQuery handler, like

  - `$('.mGrid input[id$="txtValore"]').on('change', function(){` or
  - `$('.mGrid input[id$="txtValore"]').change(function(){` but delegated events are more flexible.
- the `[id$=""]` selector is an *ends-with* selector as your actual IDs *start* with a generate prefix.
- A delegated event handler works by listening for events to bubble-up to a *non-changing ancestor element* (in this case with a class of `.mGrid`), *then* applying the jQuery selector to the elements in the bubble-chain *that caused the event*, *then* applying the function. This works for dynamically added elements too as the selector is run at event time and not *event-registration* time.

**Update: ID generation changed**

In comment you mention the ID generation changed so that the suffix was no longer at the end of the id (a underscore and number was appended). jQuery also has an *attribute contains* selector `*=` which would change the example code to:

```
// Shortcut DOM ready handler
$(function(){
    // Listen for change events bubbling up to the grid, 
    // then match elements with ID containing "txtValore"
    $('.mGrid').on('change', 'input[id*="txtValore"]' function(){

          // this is the *txtValore field that changed
          var $input = $(this);

          // Find the matching input by looking up (to closest row) and then down the tree
          // for an element with ID containing "txtRicalcolato"
          var $otherInput = $input.closest('tr').find('input[id*="txtRicalcolato"]');

          // now do "something" with the two inputs :)
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the question.. I'm not getting what do you mean.. Surrounding all the grid in a div or table? Or just the row containing the elements?

Comment: OK! Now I got it.. alert('TEST ' + $("#" + txtID).closest(tr).find("[id*='txtRicalcolato']").val());

Comment: But what do you mean by using a single delegated event handler?

Comment: @MisterFrank: updated answer to explain delegated event handling, applied to your example.

Comment: I really like that solution, but I can not make it work... Tried also $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('Ready!!');
            $(".mGrid").on("click", function () {
                alert('Ciao');
            });
        });  and having a weird behaviour.. I've a first grid with that class, having it work.. Then moving to second page, with grid of the question, same class, but not working. Come back to first page, not working anymore.. Due to postback?

Comment: P.S. I've stopped using end-with selector because moving to test environment I've the same rendered as "MainContent_grid_txtValore_0".. And a lot of time wasted figure out why not working.. maybe different IIS..

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, when I say 'Then moving to second page' what I really mean was Then I click on a button that hide the first gridview and show another, with a postback, but still same page..

Comment: @MisterFrank: The example shown should be sound, but a single trivial error can stop something "working" (like the ID generation changing). There is a "contains" selector like `'[id*="txtValore"]'` which will match both cases you have shown. Now is a good time to post a new question, with all the code *you are attempting* so that specific example can be corrected. Cheers :)

Comment: @MisterFrank:: The example now updated to cater for the match being anywhere in the ID attribute. If problems persist, please post a new question and drop a link here. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks again! When I talk about the end-with selector I mean that's why I used the contains in the original question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934872/losing-jquery-delegated-event-handler