# losing jquery Delegated Event Handler

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I've to do some stuff when a changed occure in a TextBox in a GridView.. So I've:

```
$(function () {
    $('.mGrid').on('change', 'input[id*="txtValore"]', function () {
        alert('CHANGE!!');
        (...)
    });
});
```

The situation is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="FlussiPagamento" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        (...)
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlHome" runat="server">
            (...)
            <asp:GridView ID="gridPrincipale" CssClass="mGrid">
                (...)
                <asp:TemplateField> 
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValore" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:N}", Eval("Valore"))%>'
                        runat="server"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                (...)
            </asp:GridView>
            (...)
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDettaglio" Visible="false" runat="server">
            (...)
            <asp:GridView ID="grid" CssClass="mGrid">
                (...)
                <asp:TemplateField> 
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValore" Width="90%" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:N}", Eval("Valore"))%>' runat="server"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                (...)
            </asp:GridView>
            (...)
        </asp:Panel>
        (...)
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Rendered like this:

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_UpdatePanelID">
    (...)
    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_pnlHome">
        <table class="mGrid" id="ctl00_MainContent_gridPrincipale">
            (...)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grdFlusso$ctl02$txtValore" type="text" value="1.920.442,73" id="ctl00_MainContent_gridPrincipale_ctl02_txtValore" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    (...)
    (This part when Visible=true)
    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_pnlDettaglio">
        (...)
        <table class="mGrid" id="ctl00_MainContent_grid">
            <tbody>
                (...)
                <tr>
                    (...)
                    <td>
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grid$ctl03$txtValore" value="1.693,44" id="ctl00_MainContent_grid_ctl03_txtValore" onchange="test(this.id)" type="text">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grid$ctl03$txtRicalcolato" value="169,34" id="ctl00_MainContent_grid_ctl03_txtRicalcolato" onchange="test(this.id)" type="text">
                    </td>
                    (...)
                    <td>
                        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_grid_ctl03_lblDelta">-1.524,10</span>
                    </td>
                    (...)
                </tr>
                (...)
            </tbody>
        </table>
        (...)
    </div>
    (...)
</div>
```

In the first GridView I've also an ImageButton that does second griview databound and switch the panels visibility..In the second Panel I've another ImageButton, outside the GridView, that does the opposite.. I think both of it does a postback, because I can see the entire page is reloaded.. Now the behaviour is, when the first time the page is loaded if I change the first grid TextBox text I can see the alert. After I click the ImageButton and switch to second panel, the event is not fired when change text on second grid and if I come back to first panel, it don't work anymore not even with the first one.. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button "that switches panels" replaces the current grid, you need to delegate it back to a *higher* non-changing ancestor:

e.g. `document`

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '.mGrid input[id*="txtValore"]', function () {
        alert('CHANGE!!');
        (...)
    });
});
```

This now reads as... if any change event bubbles up to `document`, run the `'.mGrid input[id*="txtValore"]'` selector to find the element that caused it, *then* fire the function against that element.

**note:** `document` is just your fallback default if nothing else is closer *that does not change*. Do not use `'body'` as styling can cause it to not receive bubbled mouse events.